# Python function to count divisible numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list, function, typeerror

I need to write a python function that takes a list as the input and calculates the number of numbers divisible by some other number, n. This is the code I have so far:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0PRR.png)

Could someone advice me on what approach to take, please?

I tried a for loop that finds the divisible numbers and adds them to a counter, but that is not working.

Comment: “*I tried a for loop that finds the divisible numbers and adds it to a counter, but that is not working.*” Please edit your question to include this attempt as a [mre] in accordance with [ask].

Comment: Please don't put in *image* - the actual code should be posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the length of an integer, count, when you probably want to return the count itself:

```
def count_divisible(lst, n):
    count = 0
    for i in lst:
        if i % n == 0:
            count += 1
    return count
```

You can shorten your function and make it safer by checking each item is actually an int or a float:

```
def count_divisible_short_and_safe(lst: list, n: int) -> int:
    return len([x for x in lst if isinstance(x, (int, float)) and x % n == 0])

assert count_divisible_short_and_safe([2,3,4,5, "foo"], 2) == 2
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly indicated the *problem*. So you could fix it and make it working like this:

```py
def count_divisible(L, n):
    count = 0
    for x in L:
        if x % n == 0:
            count += 1
    return count                  # just return the counts

# version 2 - Generator Expression 
def count_divisible2(L, n):
    return sum(1 for x in L if not x % n)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert count_divisible([2,3,4,5], 2) == 2
```